# Find all mongo query with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm developing a back end with spring data and a mongo db database.

I got the following class

```
@Document
public class Place
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @GeoSpatialIndexed
    private Double[] location;
    private int[] category;
    //gets and sets
}
```

So I want to made a query to get the places near a Point that have the selected categories, So I got this:

```
public List<Place> getPlacesNear(Double[] location, int[] category){
        NearQuery geoNear = NearQuery.near(location[0],location[1],Metrics.KILOMETERS).maxDistance(KM_DISTANCE);
        Query categoryQuery = new Query(new Criteria("category").all(category));
        geoNear.query(categoryQuery);
        GeoResults<Place> geoNearResult = mongoTemplate.geoNear(geoNear, Place.class);
        //return results
}
```

But this isn't returning any results, I know that the query.

```
db.place.find( { category: { $all: [ categoryID, categoryID2 ] } } );
```

Works well and the geoNear isn't the problem.

Is a silly question but the documentation and examples of the Spring Data for Mongo are very basic, any help or a link for a good tutorial or documentation could be helpful, thanks! :)

Comment: Did you know you can add your own answer and accept it (_and_ potentially gain upvotes for it), instead of editing the question with the answer. In its current state, this question appears in the _unanswered_ section which is incorrect as there is a solution. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem instead of passing

```
Query categoryQuery = new Query(new Criteria("category").all(category));
```

being category a int[], I pass a idCategory,idCategory2

```
Query categoryQuery = new Query(new Criteria("category").all(idCategory,idCategory2));
```

and it works great :)

Comment: But what is the difference? AFAIK, under the hood, Java translates var-args into array anyway...